# How to load a script only in specific Browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, browser, twemoji

What I want to do:
I want to load load
[Twemoji](https://twemoji.twitter.com)
in every Browser except Safari (Mobile/MacOS).
I've tried to do it in JS, but it didn't work:

```
function IsSafari() {


var is_safari = navigator.vendor && navigator.vendor.indexOf('Apple') > -1 &&
               navigator.userAgent &&
               navigator.userAgent.indexOf('CriOS') == -1 &&
               navigator.userAgent.indexOf('FxiOS') == -1;
  return is_safari;

} if(!IsSafari){console.log("No reliable Emoji-set detected. Loading Twemoji from cdnjs");
$.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twemoji/12.0.4/2/twemoji.min.js", function() {
   twemoji.parse(document.body);
});}
```

Comment: Consider using feature detection instead of browser detection, eg modernizr: https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses&q=emoji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can know if user is not using safari browser

```
if(!(/constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || (typeof safari !== 'undefined' && safari.pushNotification)))){
    console.log('Hey I am sure that you are not using safari browser ;)');
}else{
    console.log('Apple user detected');
}
```

I took the code from this stackoverflow question answer [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser). Plz like this answer )